# No package php-devel available CentOS

Tags: centos, php, packages

I try to install php-devel package on my CentOS VPS and I get this output :

```
No package php-devel available.
```

**I run this command :**

```
yum -y install php-devel
```

**Output :**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**PHP Version info :**

```
PHP 5.5.6 (cli) (built: Nov 18 2013 08:25:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I have CentOS release 6.4 (Final).

What I need to do ?

Comment: What does `yum search php-devel` show?

Comment: Try to force yum to download all the metadata with the command 'yum clean metadata' and then, try to run 'yum install php-devel' again. Btw, the latest version of php package available in the CentOS6 base/update repositories is 5.3.3. How did you install the php module of version 5.5.6?!? Do you use some 3rd-party repositories?!? Or do you compile it directly form the source code?!?